# two dimensional recursive knapsack

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, 2d, knapsack-problem

Say we have an array of tiles, each of size n on m, and a 2d array which serves as a board.

I would like to write a recursive function which returns true if it is possible to fit all tiles in the board, false otherwise (does not matter whether the board is filled or not, just need to use all tiles).

I have tried several ways unsuccessfully.

The solution does not have to be optimal.

Comment: If the solution doesn't have to be optimal, just try every positioning of every tile

Comment: Do you have any decent suggestion on how to? I've been trying to do just that

Comment: What question do you have, exactly? I just gave you a suggestion. That algorithm _does_ work.

Comment: "I have tried several ways unsuccesful" is not a suitable description. WHAT  have you tried and WHY did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I thought a greedy algorithm strategy might work for your requirements. I found a greedy aglorithm strategy that was implemented recursively here : www.cs.siu.edu/~mcoleman/classwork/cs330bonus/Knapsack.java

I myself have not looked through the solution in sufficient depth to tell if it will work for you. However, I am certain that one potential option you can choose from is a greedy algorithm strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. You'll need to implement the various board utility functions such as returning a list of possible board positions. I'm assuming that's ok for you - it's mainly the recursive search algorithm you are interested in.

```
boolean canFit(List<Tile> tiles, Board board) {
    if (tiles.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (Tile tile: tiles) {
            tiles.remove(tile);
            for (Position position: board.possiblePositionsFor(tile)) {
                board.addTile(tile, position);
                if (canFit(tiles, board)) 
                    return true;
                board.removeTile(tile);
            }
            tiles.add(tile);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code would be neater if you could create new tile sets with tiles removed and new boards with tiles added in a single method. Then you could get rid of all the statements to change the tile sets and boards and just replace it all with something like:

```
boolean canFit(TileSet tiles, Board board) {
    return tiles.isEmpty() || 
        tiles.stream()
            .flatmap(tile -> board.streamPossiblePositionsFor(tile)
                .filter(pos -> canFit(tiles.remove(tile), board.add(tile, pos))
            .findAny().isPresent();
}
```

Use whichever suits - the second is less efficient because it's creating lots of new tile sets and boards but it's also a bit neater.

Comment: This seems very close, just one problem - won't it ruin the recursive run if I change the whole tiles array (by removing one each time) on the loop, like you did? (Since they all use the same array of Tiles)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a nested for loop to go through every space in the 2d array to try every space.

```
for(int x = 0; x < arraysizex; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < arraysizey; y++)
        if(array[x][y] != filled)
        {
            //do something
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I believe the tiles are different sizes so may or may not be able to fit in the grid.

Comment: okay if you check to see if the xy coord is not filled go thorugh each tile and see if it fits into the current xy coord inside the if statement.